# Returning a queryable get result as IHttpActionResult or HttpMessageResponse from an oData Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I want to return a queryable data from an action that results either IHttpActionResult or HttpMessageResponse, since returning IQueryable causes all properties of the class be returned. I want to return a result with selected only properties from the class. But implementing this creates an error as below:
**Cannot create an EDM model as the action 'Get' on controller 'xxx' has a return type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult' that does not implement IEnumerable.**
I have seen samples from codeplex but i dont find any difference in my codes except they are made for console application.
Is there any thing i am missing?